# How can I reduce my Kafka topic into a ktable of most recent state

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have some dummy data of manufacturers in a topic keyed by entity id:

```
{"ROWTIME": 1581884260481, "ROWKEY": "key1", "name": "nissan", "id": "key1", "founded": 1910}
{"ROWTIME": 1581884260481, "ROWKEY": "key2", "name": "toyota", "id": "key2", "founded": 0}
{"ROWTIME": 1581894249560, "ROWKEY": "key2", "name": "toyota", "id": "key2", "founded": 1920}
```

1) I'd like to end up with a ktable containing the reduced state of the manufacturers:

```
{"name": "nissan", "id": "key1", "founded": 1910},
{"name": "toyota", "id": "key2", "founded": 1920}
```

Q: What is the query syntax in ksql to produce that reduced state?

All of the docs were written prior to the pull/push query changes so I am not sure how I am supposed to build this.  Do I want a materialized view (which requires aggregates), or a ktable over a topic?  Do I need a CTaS?

1b) I've been thinking about this and it would probably be best if the topic stored just changes and not the whole record.  In that scenario I can just write events that will ultimately reduce into part of the state, instead of having to query the current record or trust the UI to pass back in the whole thing.

2) When I query this table I'd like two things to happen:

- Give me the list of reduced state (the 2 records above)
- If any updates happen (insert or update to the reduced list) send them over as they happen

Q: What query can I create to give both current and future values in a ktable?

`emit changes` seems to only go forward from that point in time.  Do I need two queries, or is there a way to do it in one?

Thanks for helping me fill in these gaps, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"rowtime" and "rowkey" are default fields added by "Ksql_server", which are useful columns during stream/table join (Windowing and partition).

1. 1a) You can skip the columns at consumer level.  1b) didn;t able to
   understand :(
2. The link will be helpful
   (https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-tables-part-1-event-streaming/)
3. You don;t need to make any change because if you have created a
   KTable, new record will append only, which you can check with select
   query.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I don't think this answers the question(s).  I am not concerned with ROWTIME and ROWKEY, unless there is some having or group by clause on ROWKEY I need to make this happen, but rather the ksql query to create the table of projections.  The link provided covers creating a table with aggregates; I am looking to left fold state into the previous state.